# How to select a fix range of rows of only 2 columns in a pandas dataframe from CSV file of 10 columns?

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have 1000 rows in my dataset and I need to append rows 100 to 200 to another dataframe.

```
import glob 
import pandas as pd
allFiles = glob.glob("*.csv")
dfs = []

for filename in allFiles:
    dfs.append(pd.read_csv(filename, usecols=["timeInterval_str", "Root"], loc[106:152] ))

 print(dfs)
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Sorry about that. I have some 9 CSV files and want to read two similar columns from each file and plot the specific range of rows once the columns are selected.

Comment: please leave the code formatted properly so people can read

Comment: Ok. Is it ok now or still ambiguous ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need instead:

```
loc[106:152]
```

use parameters `skiprows` and `nrows` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
#first row is column name, so range 
skiprows=range(1,107), nrows=46
```

All together:

```
for filename in allFiles:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, 
                     usecols=["timeInterval_str", "Root"], 
                     skiprows=range(1,107), 
                     nrows=46)
    dfs.append(df)

df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
print(df)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151206/discussion-on-answer-by-jezrael-how-to-select-a-fix-range-of-rows-of-only-2-colu).